# XSS + .net: Downsides of using validaterequest = true

Tags: .net, xss

I working on **XSS(cross site scripting)** issues of my web application. The app has many user controls that take user inputs.

I came across this article http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/request-validation

Can you please answer the below questions:

Are there any downsides of using **validateRequest="true"** at application level (in web.config)?

Is there any better way to fix XSS issues apart from going on each and every control and doing HTML encode?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2559337/why-isnt-validaterequest-true-enough-for-xss-prevention

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something that initially springs to mind is the following:

If you are retrospectively adding `validateRequest` to a site then any user input that contained malicious scripts that you have already captured and stored in a database is still a vulnerability for your application, `validateRequest` wont protect you here, HTML Encoding will.

It may be a pain to plough your way through your app and HTML Encode everything, if you are really bothered then this is a necessary evil. Hackers are always coming up with new methods. If you use a Library you will have to wait for updates to patch new holes, while leaving your site vulnerable - I believe HTML Encode is your best weapon to defend against XSS attacks.

Having said that, give this a quick read:

[Will HTML Encoding prevent all kinds of XSS attacks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53728/will-html-encoding-prevent-all-kinds-of-xss-attacks)